# Is this AJAX pattern a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Consider this example of pretty standard method in Angular Js, which updates the view:

```
$scope.fetchResults = function() {
    // Some local variable that will cause creation of closure
    var hugeData = serviceX.getMilionRecords();

    // Any call to any resource with success and error handlers.
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/rest-api/bulk-operation-x",
        params: { someParam: hugeData.length }

    }).success( function () {
        var length = hugeData.length;
        $scope.reportToUser("Success, that was " + length + " records being processed!";

    }).error( function () {
        var length = hugeData.length;
        $scope.reportToUser("Something went wrong while processing " + length + " records... :-(";
    });
};
```

This is of course hypothetical example, but it nicely shows pattern, which could be described as **reusing of local variables from within AJAX callbacks.**

Of course in both handlers (`success` and `error`) we are creating a closure over `hugeData` which is directly referenced from callback handlers.

My question is: since the result of AJAX call can be only either success or failure, will reusing of this code cause the memory leak over time? I would answer "yes", but I couldn't reliably prove this one in my local tests.

I'd like some more experienced guru to explain this one for me. I'd love response from anyone working with Angular  on daily basis, but any jquery responses are welcome as well.

Comment: "Memory leak" is a very specific term that refers to memory being allocated and subsequently never freed. It applies only to contexts where memory management is done manually. Given that in JS management is transparent to the programmer, memory leaks are only relevant if talking about coding patterns that cause a buggy implementation to leak memory under certain circumstances, as was the case with older versions of IE. I 'm not sure if the question makes sense as written.

Comment: I don't agree with @Jon's comment. A bad practice may cause memory leaks, like filling up objects in the global scope, etc. In this case it won't, because the hugeData variable is deleted as soon as any of the callback is finished (and the $http instance is cleaned up)

Comment: @Jon, you can very easily create a memory leak in any language with transparent memory management. Java, Scala, JavaScript, C#, you name it. 
@rewritten, this is exactly what I'm talking about. How do you know that `hugeData` is deleted when `success()` finishes? From language point of view, the closure used in `error()` might be executed at some later time in future. Unless Angular does something under the hood (like nullifying the other callback when one finishes), then we could very well have a memory leak here.

Comment: You are correct, see my other comment, angularJS's `$q` implementation takes care of cleaning up the callback chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have a memory leak as soon as you return the result of `$http()` call (or whatever object or function that has access to `hugeData`) into the outer scope of `fetchResults`.

With your code, nothing big is exposed directly outside of `fetchResults`, and the result of `$http()` call will live until it either succeeds or fail, then calling the corresponding callback, finally getting GC'ed.

See for insights: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIdRes

As @ŁukaszBachman observes, this does not guarantee that there are no memory leaks. Any dangling reference to your big object or to your callback with big object in scope, will cause woe.

So, let's check into `$q` implementation (`$http` is based on `$q`).

If you check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L191, you can see that the `resolve()` method of the deferred first copies the list of registered callbacks in a variable local to the method:

```
var callbacks = pending;
```

subsequently nullifies the external `pending` (that was defined at the `defer` level)

```
pending = undefined;
```

then, at next tick, executes the callbacks. Things may get complicated by the fact that the callback's argument may be a deferred itself (adding a further delay to execution), but at most you could get into an infinite loop. (And that's not funny!). If you are lucky enough not to get into the loop, then at some point the callback array is exhausted, and then there is no reference whatsoever to the callback list, so it's available for GC.

But.

Things may go wrong if you force them to.

You may use arguments.callee inside a callback.

You can throw beer on your keyboard too.

If you jump out of the window, unless you live on the first floor, you will probably get hurt.

Happy EcmaScripting!

Comment: Why are you sure about `the result of $http() call will live until it either succeeds or fail`? AFAIU the closure is managed my the JS engine itself, so from my example you cannot be sure, right? You would have to check the inner impl of `$http` to verify that the second callback gets disposed and can thus be freed by GC.
Am I correct?
(I've added provided article to my read list)

Comment: Check `$q` implementation, particularly the `resolve` method (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L191). The `pending` callback chain is completely removed from the promise's scope as soon as the promise is resolved, and it's internalized into another variable in the resolve method. Once the resolve is complete, no more references to the callbacks remains, making them available for GC.

Comment: In other words, you are correct. And it's done exactly that way, the full list of registered callbacks is cleaned up in the resolve process.

Comment: Perfect, just as I thought. I'm slowly mastering the nature of JS so I wanted to understand this all correctly. Perhaps you could take your comment and edit the answer for further JS/Angular explorers? :)